# Create an 2d Isometric map with tiles?

Tags: c#, unity, tilemap, isometric

I'm creating a 2D Tower Defense game and I want it to be isometric. I'm creating it on the XZ plane in Unity(3D mode). I need the map to be based on tiles so I can seperate the monsters' path and the tiles where the player will build the towers on because they will have different scripts attached to 'em. My game will just need one map so I dont need any functionalty like randomizing tiles etc. I've tried using Tiled however, the Tiled2Unity converter doesn't support Isometric maps.

With that said, how do I create a isometric map? Is there any program other than Tiled? Is there any guides or scripts that explain how to create one with different tiles etc, so I can create a path. I've tried looking for something that works but with no results/I dont understand what do do.

This is basicly the look(the angle/path) I want to achieve: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D objects still have an X and Z coordinate. The only thing you have to do to make it isometric in 3D settings is to ensure the Y value for all the tile objects are the same. Generally we set this to 0. Put your camera wherever you like the angle, and voila! 
I hope this clears things up.

Comment: It's not helpful to anyone to downvote unless you have a reason why my solution is not helpful.